# Destroy Current Activity using notification Android

Tags: android

**MainActivity** is opened in My app. Consider this scenario,

when **MainActivity(1) is currently running.**  Notification comes, user clicks and **Mainactivity(2) gets opened**. It works. When I click back button. **Mainactivity(2)** gets destroyed.  **MainActivity(1)** is shown to user and app freezes. I was looking for a way to close **MainActivity(1)**.

```
NotificationManagerCompat manager =   NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    notificationIntent, 0);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
manager.notify(123,builder.build());
```

Comment: Instead of that, you could check if MainActivity is running, and avoid creating MainActivity 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added "singleTop" in the Manifest file. It worked for both scenarios. When an activity is currently display and App is in the background.

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"></activity>
```